# Three js css3d render pixilated on safari

Tags: three.js

does anyone know why this may be happening, the scene renders fine on everything else.

[image]

but on safari it looks like this:

[image]

they are are html divs. i have tried svg background jpeg and png backgrounds.
result is still the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that Object3D elements are sized in abstract “units”, but CSS3D elements are sized in pixels. So if you have a `Mesh` with a width of 4, then the CSS3D element has to have CSS `width: 4px;` to match, and some browsers will literally only render 4 pixels (Safari).

To alleviate this, I've found that scaling down the CSS scene by a factor of 10 will allow you to add more pixels to your CSS elements:

```js
cssScene = new THREE.Scene();
cssScene.scale.set(0.1, 0.1, 0.1);
```

now you can use `width: 40px` instead of just 4. Keep in mind that you'll also have to multiply the object positions by 10: `label.position.multiplyScalar(10)`

Comment: ok that seems to work, i have some work ahead of me to reposition everything along with all the camera tweens. but now i know for the future, thank you Marquizzo, if you don't own a cape already you should definitely get one.